# Free trail for a specific subscription item while subscription is not on trial in stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I have one active subscription. Now I want to add new subscription item to that subscription but that on free trial while other items on that subscription are active.

How do I achieve this thing.

I read the documentation where we can set `trail_end` for subscription but there is no field for subscription item.

Any help must be appreciated.

In stripe panel in that plan I have added trial period but than also in invoice it deduct the price.

Answer (score 1):

In a same Subscription, you can't have a single Subscription item with trial, and others Subscription items that don't. Trial is for the whole Subscription itself.

Comment: yes but in stripe admin panel if we create any plan we can add trial period time than what  is the use of that?